# Can I script an Apache http shutdown or use AutoIT to make a tool that restarts it for me?

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, script, httpd

I do cross-platform development for Linux and Windows 10. I would like a nice way to restart Apache http with Windows 10. I use the Apache Lounge version for Windows. Everything works but I restart httpd.exe by forcing it with ctrl+c and then manually restarting it. I have a script to restart the python intepreter on Linux and that way I don't have to restart apache. But it works to restart Apache on Windows to load new changes.

Can I script an Apache http shutdown or use AutoIT to make a tool that restarts it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I script an Apache http shutdown or restart?

You can use the following `httpd` commands in a batch file or other scripting language of your choice (make sure the apache binary directory is in your path)

To gracefully stop the server:

```
httpd -k graceful-stop
```

To restart the server:

```
httpd -k restart
```

Source [httpd - Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html)